# RAM intermittently not recognized

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

My MBP will sometimes drop 4 of the 8G of RAM I have after recovering from sleep or a reboot.  One (or more) restarts later I'll have all 8G again.  Is this a memory stick going bad?  Could it be something worse?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it could easily easily be a bad connection on the ram chip or just bad connection of the RAM stick with connector on the motherboard. Try to clean RAM connectors with a gum eraser first.

To test memory under load you may also use [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) CD if your MBP is Core 2 Duo one or Apple Hardware Test from included CD if yours is "Core i" one.

Comment: How does one clean the RAM bays with a gum eraser? The slots are very tiny. I might go in there with compressed air.

Comment: @xanadont I told you to clean connectors on RAM sticks, not on the slot end.

Comment: Oh, that's not clear, you might want to refer to them as the prongs on the RAM. "Connectors" sounds like the receiving end of it. But, word, I'll give that a try and also compressed air. Is there *any* way to diagnose if the bay is going bad?

Comment: @xanadont If there is a way to diagnose that I believe it involves some special equipment.